# API: Time complexity of modifers.find()

Tags: python, scripting

Suppose it has many of modifiers in a single object,
given that a modifier in that object, I want to find out the index:

```
def ret_ind(mds, md):
    return mds.find(md.name)
```

If I am sure that modifier is 100% in the object modifiers, is there a faster way to get that modifier index?

Comment: if you know the modifier is in the list, and you have a pointer to the modifier, why do you want the index?  It might matter to an answer.  Anyway, since modifiers is [bpy_prop_collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html) type, I don't think there's any other way to get the index than `find`.

Comment: because I want the index to calculate something in the addon. The index sometime changed by the user.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of modifiers on your object or you run this code thousands of times per second, this shouldn't be noticeable in the slightest. Did you happen to notice poor performance on this particular piece of code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a definitive answer, I went to the source code.  `bpy_prop_collection`, as the documentation indicates is not an actual Python class.  Rather, I suspect for performance reasons, it is implements in [`bpy_rna.c`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c).

You can start to track down the code that computes the index at line [2374](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c#L2347).  This is provided in the form of a macro definition. It uses `RNA_property_collection_length`; defined at line [3914](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_access.c#L3914) of `rna_acces.c`.

You can take these things from this code evaluation:

1. This is the *only* way of determining the index.
2. It has $O(n)$ time complexity.  Given the data structures used, there isn't a faster approach.
3. It's optimized C code.

So the answer to your question is that no there isn't a faster way.